Nvidia proprietary driver can't start due to key error
I use a laptop with a hybrid (Intel + Nvidia) graphics setup, running Kubuntu 24.10, with secureboot enabled. My current kernel (output of uname -r) is 6.11.0-9-generic.
After a recent update (not sure what exactly, but I suspect the kernel update from 6.11.0-8-generic to 6.11.0-9-generic), my Nvidia card appears to have completely stopped working - external displays aren't getting detected regardless of whether I use X or Wayland, and I don't see the card's details in the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" app anymore.
lshw shows the card as an UNCLAIMED display device, suggesting no driver wanted to deal with my Nvidia GPU (also suggested by no driver name being shown under its "configuration" section:
wisp@transient > ~ > sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:150 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
wisp@transient > ~ >

This seems to point to a driver issue, and looking at dkms status nvidia it seems like my driver (the proprietary one) installed just fine (the scary warnings above seem to relate to the older kernel version that I am not on), but indeed isn't being used:
wisp@transient > ~ > sudo dkms status nvidia
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.11.0-8-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.11.0-9-generic, x86_64: installed
wisp@transient > ~ >

Trying to sudo modprobe nvidia manually leads to modprobe yelling at me about a key error:
wisp@transient > ~ > sudo modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service
wisp@transient > ~ > 

This is the part that confuses me, since I used to use the proprietary driver on this exact machine, so if this really is a signing issue I'd expect it to have happened sooner. How could I be having a key error now but not earlier and, more importantly, how do I fix this?
edit: fix fisspelling dkms to dmks in body (non-codeblock) text

What happens if you sudo ubuntu-drivers install? It should update the nvidia driver packages accordingly.

@popey Running sudo ubuntu-drivers install just tells me I already have the latest drivers: "All the available drivers are already installed."

I'd be inclined to reinstall the driver package manually then. e.g. if the version installed is 550, sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-550. On my 24.04 system, I have 550 currently, and no nvidia dkms packages.

@popey reinstalled and rebooted, sadly no change. Device is still unclaimed, driver still isn't loaded

I think something was just wrong with my DKMS. When upgrading from the kernel in the question (6.11.0-9-generic) first to 6.11.0-12-generic and now to 6.11.0-13-generic, DKMS appears to be working just fine, signing the Nvidia drivers without any issues.
Excerpt from 6.11.0-13-generic log (part of sudo apt-get upgrade)
Setting up linux-headers-6.11.0-13-generic (6.11.0-13.14) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.11.0-13-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j12 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.11.0-13-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1
 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules...................
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia.ko
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia-modeset.ko
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia-drm.ko
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia-uvm.ko
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/nvidia-peermem.ko
Cleaning build area...

nvidia.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.11.0-13-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod...
dkms autoinstall on 6.11.0-13-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.11.0-13-generic
   ...done.

And the new dmks status nvidia:
wisp@transient > ~ > sudo dkms status nvidia
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.11.0-12-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/560.35.03, 6.11.0-13-generic, x86_64: installed


I have the same issue as well. I've been all over the internet looking for a solution and have found everything from kernel module loading configuration (requiring signed modules, some say, doesn't appear to be the issue esp with ubuntu based distros) to secure boot issues. it seems like secure boot is the culprit here. Ubuntu (and their derivatives) are not properly updating the keys on secure boot enabled systems, which causes the driver to fail to load.
I have yet to test this personally, but the consensus seems to point to secure boot. I really don't like having to disable secure boot if I can avoid it, and really shouldn't have to just to get a driver working that someone was too lazy to get working with secure boot properly.
I have the exact same setup: Acer Predator Helios 18 with Intel embedded graphics on the processor (i9-14900hx, comes with Raptor Lake-S UHD graphics), and an Nvidia RTX 4090. I get the key error when trying to load the module as well, and have the dkms package. I also tried installing the other driver package suggested above and no change. Still broken.
Only fix I know of to get this working at all (if you want to call creating a gaping security hole in your system a "fix") is to disable secure boot altogether and hope to god you don't get any malware that screws with your boot files. :/
They really need to fix this. Looking at the search results, this crap has been going on for years and the only thing anyone has done to address it is spitball some fixes that MAY work for a little while until an update breaks things again.
Unfortunately, this seems like a no-win scenario until someone actually addresses and fixes this issue properly.

Thanks for posting here since it made me remember the question. I ended up just manually signing the driver file with a key I enrolled into UEFI myself. It works, and doesn't cause a security hole like disabling SB. The reason I'm hesitant to answer my own question with this is that It'll just break and need to be redone after either a kernel update or a driver update, so I consider this more of a workaround than a proper fix. Maybe one day...

Yeah I found the same thing too, eventually. My drivers are loading now but who knows on the next kernel/driver update. The page I got it from also had a script to automate all this, but it was for another distro and the post was at least year old, possibly more. At first glance, adapting the script to work on an Ubuntu (or debian based at all) distro would be quite a bit of work. I Basically had to do some stuff with MOK key and enrolling. I'll try to find the link if I can, at least so people can get their drivers working temporarily at least.

Alright, so I updated my kernel to 6.11.0-12-generic (from 6.11.0-9-generic) and NVIDIA drivers worked immediately, showing up in lsmod and claiming the display in sudo lshw -c display
